# Replacing a specific substring with another substring in a string in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, string

I've the following requirement. I'm passing 'ABC DEF' as a command parameter @MyString to a stored procedure. In the stored procedure level i need to replace the substring DEF with XYZ to get the string 'ABC XYZ'. How can i do that?

Thank you.
NLV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the replace function within T-SQL

```
declare @myOriginalString varchar(50)
set @myOriginalString = 'ABC DEF'
declare @myfindstring varchar(50)
set @myfindstring = 'DEF'
declare @myReplaceString varchar(50)
set @myReplaceString = 'XYZ'

select replace(@myOriginalString,@myFindString, @myReplaceString)
```

Comment: Very quick. Great! Thank you Andrew.